# Adding colorizer tests to an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My team and I built a [colorizer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer) that highlights colors in the logging output in VSCode.  In the core extensions there are colorize tests that get called automatically with VSCode since they are bundled in.

I was wondering how to call the colorize tests for an extension that is not bundled in VSCode.

Source code [available here](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/vscode-log-output-colorizer).

Comment: It appears that @MartinAeschlimann has been working on those test fixtures and/or results.  Hopefully, he will be able to answer this.